# How do you match a specific cookie value with Apache 2.4 <If> statement?

Tags: htaccess, apache2, cookie

I am not able to figure out why the following doesn't match:

```
<If %{HTTP_COOKIE} == 'XDEBUG_SESSION=leho'">
```

I'm setting a php_value inside the matching If. I know that part works because this seems to match something

```
%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /leho/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTP_COOKIE` is a semi-colon delimited list of all the cookies that are set.   Your `==` test would only work if your cookie were the *only* one set.   Instead, I would try this regular expression match in the `<If>` directive:

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /XDEBUG_SESSION=leho/">
```

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I ended up getting to later that night, and it worked. I may have missed the // regex delimiters or something at first try.